# how to get json object and set it to listview before listview get set in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After moving to a new page i want to automatically set data from JSON that i am getting from host and put it into ListView. Actually ListView is setting up before JSON is downloaded. I am looking for solution where ListView is setting up after the JSON deserialisation is done. Here is my code.

```
public async void DownloadMapsFromServer()
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://10.0.2.2:44353/v1/RaceMaps/");
        var jsonlist = new List<RaceMapBindingModel>();
        jsonlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RaceMapBindingModel>>(content);

    }

    public MapsList()
    {
        DownloadMapsFromServer();

        Label header = new Label
        {
            Text = "ListView",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        // Define some data.
        List<MapsListView> Maps = new List<MapsListView>();

            foreach (RaceMapBindingModel item in jsonlist)
            {
            Maps.Add(new MapsListView($"{item.Name}", $"{item.Description}", Color.Red));
            }
```

Comment: how do you bring jsonlist from DownloadMapsFromServer to MapsList method?

Comment: Use a observable collection as your bindable property to your visual list in the xaml. It will update automatically as soon as items are added to the list

Comment: @Jawad This is not my whole code. I set jsonlist as public for whole class.

Comment: @Greggz Thank you, i have to read about it. Actually i chose the easy way. Instead of HttpClient.GetAsync i used webClient.DownloadString. With this program works synchronously and page appears after the JSON is downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of using the HttpClient.GetAsync i used the WebClient.DownloadString method.

Comment: Could you please mark your reply as an answer so that others who have similar question will get help from here?